# Register svg as mat-icon from web application URL

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an svg image in my application and accessiple via http://localhost:8080/product_backend_war_exploded/common/images/trash.svg.

I want to use this image as mat-icon in my angular material front-end so I can change the color and use the mat-icon options when needed. But, when tried to register it like this

```
public registerSvgIconFromServer(url) {
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1), this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url));
}
```

I git this error:

Error retrieving icon :trash.svg! Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/product_backend_war_exploded/common/images/trash.svg: 0 Unknown Error